# nested navigator that can work inside its parent or fixed component in all navigator screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux, react-native-navigation

I am trying to create a tablet application, and I want my layout to have a sidebar and then content inside but I'm not able to do that I tried searching for how to create a nested navigator that will work independently of its parent and render inside its parent but wasn't able to find any help about it anyone knows how to do that or if its possible to define a fixed component for all navigator children.

I tried working on react-native-navigation, react-navigation and react-native-router-flux but none of them till now have helped me with my problem, anyone got any solution?

sorry if it wasn't clear, please ask questions in the comment if you didn't understand what I'm trying to reach

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using React Navigation by Facebook where you can create a navigator and a view but either one that is preceeding the other won't show if you don't give it height and width

```
<View>
  <View style={{ height: "100%", width: 150 }}>
    <SideBar navigation={navigation} />
  </View>
  <View>
    <ContentNavigator />
  </View>
</View>
```